# Android - Query all documents from subcollection as objects - Firestore realtime database

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a model class `Appointment` that has a type as field, ***I need to listen and get all the documents from it's `subCollection` in Firestore realtime database***, the upload logic works perfectly but since it's practically my first time diving into firestore I am having some troubles in getting the data.

after getting the documents ***I need to separate them by type*** (Appointment type_A, Appointment type_B)

This is what I got so far but I can't seem to get past that!

PS. Below code is mainly based on Firebase Documentation!

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    //get all appointments
    mFirestore.collection("reporters").document(mUser.getUid()).collection("appointments")
            .addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onEvent(@Nullable QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
                    mFirestore.collection("reporters").document().collection("appointments")
                            .whereEqualTo("type", "typeB")
                            .addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onEvent(@Nullable QuerySnapshot value,
                                                    @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
                                    if (e != null) {
                                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "listen failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        return;
                                    }

                                    for (QueryDocumentSnapshot doc : value) {
                                        if (doc.get("name") != null) {
                                            v_appointmentsList.add(doc.toObject(Appointment.class));
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                    mFirestore.collection("reporters").document().collection("appointments")
                            .whereEqualTo("type", "typeA")
                            .addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onEvent(@Nullable QuerySnapshot value,
                                                    @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
                                    if (e != null) {
                                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "listen failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        return;
                                    }

                                    for (QueryDocumentSnapshot doc : value) {
                                        if (doc.get("name") != null) {
                                            p_appointmentsList.add(doc.toObject(Appointment.class));
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                    //get all docs
                    //....
                    //sort by date [max -> min || min -> max]
                    //...
                    //get index [0] || index [last]
                    //...
                    //if it is vax then affect to variables v_
                    //if it is ped then affect to variables p_
                }
            });
}
```

Comment: Please pay close attention to the product tags: the Realtime Database and Cloud Firestore are two different databases. While both are part of Firebase, they have different APIs, and different tags. You should seldom need to tag a question with both.

Comment: Please add your database structure as a screenshot and please also responde with @AlexMamo

Comment: @AlexMamo you mean a screenshot from the Firebase console? I don't quite get what you mean

Comment: Yes, a screenshot from the Firebase console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your case I suggest you do the following (I based this answer on the commented section below), for similar cases using Realtime database is not critical and you can try and do this method instead:

```
//colRef is a reference/path to your collection
//filter by type with .whereEqualTo("field", "type")


colRef.whereEqualTo("type", "yourType")
            .get()
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : Objects.requireNonNull(task.getResult())) {
                            //add to your arraylist
                        }
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "fail to get docs", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });


//repeat the process for the second type
//if you have more types I suggest using another approach
```